# creating template function with different parameters

Tags: c++, templates

So for example I want to create a function that add two numbers and return total.

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
T1 add( T1 n1, T2 n2 ){
    return n1 + n2;
}
```

Problems is if `T1` is `int` and `T2` is `float`. Then function will `return int`. But I want it to `return float`. Is there a trick or a way to achieve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes

```
template<typename RT, typename T1, typename T2>
RT add( T1 n1, T2 n2 ){
    return n1 + n2;
}
```

Now call it like:-

```
add<float>(2,3.0);
```

Comment: What would be syntax for arithmetic operators?

Answer (score 10):

If you are using `C++11`

`decltype` is your friend

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
auto add( T1 n1, T2 n2 ) -> decltype(n1 + n2) {
    return n1 + n2;
}
```

This will use the type resulting from `n1 + n2`

More at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Alternative_function_syntax

Answer (score 3):

If you are using C++14:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
auto add(T1 n1, T2 n2)
{
   return n1 + n2;
}
```

This is like the C++11 version, but does not require you to write out the *trailing-return-type* yourself (which is nice).

Comment: Why not `decltype(auto)`? `add` should return a reference if `operator+` for two types returns one

Comment: @Columbo: I confess I know relatively little about this stuff. Please feel free to suggest an appropriate remedy.

Answer (score 1):

Another C++11 solution would be to use `std::common_type<T1, T2>::type` as return type.